# Parallelizing for loop in python using mpi4py

Tags: python, mpi4py

The question might be trivial but I haven't found a straightforward answer to my question.

I have a for loop coded in Python 3.6 and I want to parallelize it. It goes as follows:

```
# Main file
import scipy
a=1
b=2   # ... some parameters defined
for i in range (10):
    (ans_1,ans_2) = f(a,b,i)

# Function file
def f(x,y,j):
    c = a+b    # Some calculations
    scipy.savetxt("data.csv",delimiter=',')    # Saving required variables
```

How can I parallelize the for loop in my main file using `mpi4py` module in Python 3.6? For instance, I want to specify the number of processors like we use in Matlab: `parfor(20)` and typing `parfor` instead of `for` in the loop. Please help me!

Answer (score -5, accepted):

why you need MPI? , I would suggest using something like joblib...
https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html

In your case, something like

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
# parallel on 20 cores:
Parallel(n_jobs=20)(delayed(f)((a,b,i)) for i in range(10))
# Function file
def f(params):
    x,y,j = params
    c = a+b    # Some calculations
    scipy.savetxt("data.csv",delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Thanks @Hilman. But there is only mpi4py available in supercomputer available for my calculations. Any help on that?

Comment: Can I not write `def f(x,y,j):`? What does `def f(params):` do?